# JLabel not refreshing without needing additional threads?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread, actionevent

I'm making a countdown timer which refreshes every second.

I can't figure out for the life of me how to make the JLabel refresh. I've searched other threads, but they all involve using additional threads. Is there a way to make either the JLabel/Panel refresh? (Panel may be unnecessary). It works if I remove the while loop, which would just give me a still String of the timer at its original time, with no decrement. But if I include the while loop, it just returns a constant blank screen until the timer runs out, then it goes back to the original value.

How should I refresh the JLabel so that it will display to the GUI every time it decrements (hopefully without using threads..) ? (Or every time the while loop runs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"It works if I remove the while loop*"

You're blocking the event dispatching thread.

Swing is a single threaded framework, that means that anything the blocks the EDT will prevent from processing the Event Queue and cause the UI to hang.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

The simplest solution would be to use a Swing `Timer`, which will allow you to schedule a regular callback which will be executed from within the context of the EDT.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        counter++;
        label.setText(count);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the 500 is in milliseconds?